# How to find numbers higher than 25 in my table in R?

Tags: r

For a homework assignment I need to analyse a table about bmi, age and sex in **R** and I'm really struggling to find  data higher than 25 in the column bmi. I read something about finding the data that's on a specific spot in the table but not how to find data itself.

In short: The bmi data varies from 15-35 and I need to filter all bmi data above 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subset(df, bmi > 25)

df[df$bmi > 25,]
```

[R intro](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf)

And your question should have runnable code so people can really see the problem and make a useful answer.

Comment: well yes but i couldn't insert a table.. i'm new to this website so i'm figuring stuff out slowly..

Comment: @user2980003, Welcome to SO! It is fair enough that you're "figuring stuff out slowly" about _R_. But what you should do _not_ so slowly is to figure out **how to ask on SO**: [**here**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [**here**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist), [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). [About asking others to do _your_ homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions/10812#10812).